# Replacing headphone wire

Tags: headphones

I am trying to replace a broken head phone wire (with three terminals).

Here is the overview of the headphone, showing the broken part: [image: first pic]

Here is the close up of the other end, showing it has three terminals (or wires):[image: second pic]

I am thinking of buying this([https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07Y8KGJKL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07Y8KGJKL)) from amazon and replacing it. It seems like the right fit but wanted to check with experts here.

I could replace the headphone itself but my kid will break it again, so I need to learn :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work fine. You could also buy a cheaper male-male or male-female cable and cut one end, if you have a wire stripper (can also be stripped with wire cutters or even scissors and a bit of care and patience). The important bit is the 1/8"/3.5mm plug. Just make sure you check which wire goes to L/R/common before you solder. The colors are not standard. You can do this with any multimeter.